# Toggle open both ID tags

Tags: jquery

I'm a complete noob at Jquery,  so I came across this problem. As the title says how can I get both of the id tags to toggle at once, this is for a slip scorlling effect. For example if I click on #nav-icon3 it should also toggle open #nav-icon4.

Stole from: http://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#nav-icon3,#nav-icon4').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        });
    });
```

Cheers,
Jquery Noob

Answer (score 3):

No, inside the click handler `this` refers to the clicked element only so using `toggle` with `this` will toggle the class of clicked element only not of the other element.

But as a solution, you can store a reference to the jQuery object containing both the elements, then use that to register the handler and to toggle like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $btns = $('#nav-icon1,#nav-icon2,#nav-icon3,#nav-icon4').click(function() {
    $btns.toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Icon 1 */

#nav-icon1,
#nav-icon2,
#nav-icon3,
#nav-icon4 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-icon1 span,
#nav-icon3 span,
#nav-icon4 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d3531a;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
#nav-icon1 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
#nav-icon1 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 18px;
}
#nav-icon1 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 36px;
}
#nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
#nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -60px;
}
#nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
/* Icon 2 */

#nav-icon2 {} #nav-icon2 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #d3531a;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(even) {
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 9px 9px 0;
}
#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(odd) {
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px;
}
#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(1),
#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0px;
}
#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(3),
#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
}
#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(5),
#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(6) {
  top: 36px;
}
#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(1),
#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(2),
#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 5px;
  top: 7px;
}
#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(2) {
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  top: 7px;
}
#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(3) {
  left: -50%;
  opacity: 0;
}
#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(4) {
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(5) {
  left: 5px;
  top: 29px;
}
#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(6) {
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  top: 29px;
}
/* Icon 3 */

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}
#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
/* Icon 4 */

#nav-icon4 {} #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#nav-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 36px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -3px;
  left: 8px;
}
#nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
}
#nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 39px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-icon1">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="nav-icon2">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="nav-icon3">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="nav-icon4">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```